# Python default/unnamed method

Tags: python, class, object

is it possible to create a python object that has the following property:

```
class Foo:
  def __default_method__(x):
      return x

f = Foo()
f(10)
> 10
```

That is to say, an object that when instantiated allows for a method to be called without the need for an explicit method name?

Comment: This is called a functor.

Comment: In Python, we usually don't use the term "functor," because in Python, functions are first class, so the functor pattern is a solution in search of a problem.  Instead, we speak of whether an object is [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  It's called [`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).

Answer (score 3):

As Kevin pointed out in his answer, `__call__` is what you are looking for.

As a matter of fact, every time you create a class object you are using a callable class (the class's metaclass) without realizing it.

Usually we make a class this way:

```
class C(object):
    a = 1
```

But you can also make a class this way:

```
C = type('C',(object,),{'a':1})
```

The `type` class is the metaclass of all Python classes. The class `C` is *an instance* of `type`. So now, when you instantiate an object of type `C` using `C()`, you are actually **calling** the `type` class.

You can see this in action by replacing `type` with your own metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(self):
        print("MyMeta has been called!")
        super().__call__()

class C(object, metaclass = MyMeta):
    pass

c = C() # C() is a CALL to the class of C, which is MyMeta
> My Meta has been called!
```